# Delete file from a folder which is X days older

Tags: unix, ksh

I need to delete file which is 14 days older.

CMD USED:

```
find  ${FILES_DIR}/*.zip -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -delete
```

This works fine. But what if there are no zip files present in the folder? It's throwing an error. How to handle the case?

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing an error"? Spurious error message? In that case redirect standard error to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is where to start the search.
A filename-pattern is given with `-name '<pattern>` 
You should use

`find  ${FILES_DIR} -name '*.zip' -mtime +14 -delete`

In your form the `find` gets a list of starting points, but has nothing to search.

`-mindepth 1` dosn't seem to have an effect. May be you wanted to use `-maxdepth 1` to restrict the search to the mentioned directory and nothing else. (Place it before `-name`to avoid a warning

You may consider using `-ls -delete` - at least you can see what has been deleted.